# Traversing a Parent / Child Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Self-join(parent/child) table that forms a TreeView control. in this structure only leaf nodes has a [Percent] value(persists in table only for leafs). and parent nodes values calculated from children(average values of children = parent [Percent] value).

How to write a procedure or function to calculate every node [Percent] values? any suggestions? i am beginner in sql and not familiar enough in sql statements and could not find any suitable article in the web. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [recursive Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Comment: im looking for a recursive function that gets a NodeID and traverse its children till reach its value.

Comment: Than a CTE is just what you are looking fore.